# How to get font of a HTML node with python?

Tags: python, html

Now I use lxml to parse HTML in python. But I haven't found any API to get font information of a text node. Is there any librafy to do that?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Font information? You can't extract that with an XML parser. You'd have to render the webpage with an engine and hope there is a Python API which lets you do this.

Comment: There is only text, there is no font. Unless there is a font defined in a style attribute. Or in the CSS used by that HTML. But it's hard to tell. The best you can do is search for a font tag or style attribute with font changing value.

Comment: What is the problem you are looking to solve that the font information will help with?

Comment: I want to find out the top used font in a html page. Currently I get all style declarations and calculate nodes' explicit font defined in css. But I haven't fond any method to get their implicit and inherited font.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this information from the text nodes in the HTML, because it **isn't there**.